# data not sent by AJAX to Django view. Data received bt Ajax shall be sent to Django.views which not occurring

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, forms, django-views

**register.html**

```
(----this revieves the data------)
        <form  method="POST" id="someForm">
          {% csrf_token %}
      
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
      
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
      
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
      
          <input type="submit" value="Register"  name="createuser"/>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let URLd = "{% url 'defaultpg' %}";
    let nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
    let emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
    let passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");
    const someForm = document.getElementById("someForm");

    someForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior of the form
        var csrfToken = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
        let nameValue = nameInput.value;
        let emailValue = emailInput.value;
        let passwordValue = passwordInput.value;
        let isNameValid = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(nameValue);
        let isEmailValid = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(emailValue);
        let isPasswordValid = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/.test(passwordValue);
        if (isNameValid && isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
            alert("Successful");
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
(----I m not sure wether url is working or not ------)
              url: URLd,
              headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken },
              data: {
                  "name": nameValue,
                  "email": emailValue,
                  "password": passwordValue
              },
              dataType: "json",
//success is not sending data 
              success: function (data) {
                  // Handle success response
                  alert("Successful");
              },
//failure function  is working showing alert
              error: function () {
                  // Handle error response
                  alert("Failure");
              }
          });
        } else {
            // Handle validation errors
            if (!isNameValid) {
                alert("Please enter a valid Name");
            } else if (!isEmailValid) {
                alert("Please enter a valid Email Address");
            } else {
                alert("Password must contain letters, capital letter, small letter, special character, and numbers with a length above 8");
            }
        }
      
    });
</script>

   
    
  </body>
</html>
//I tried most of the things but it didn't work , I have posted a //similar question u guys check it swell
```

> Most probably the problem is in the js , but still if ny prob let me know

**views.py**

```
//I m not able to debug this issue
def defaultpg(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        import json
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        name = data.get("name")
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
        print(name,email,password)
        return render(request, 'Entry/login.html')
    return render(request, 'Entry/login.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
//this take to the view.py the above code
   path('defaultpg/', views.defaultpg, name='defaultpg'),`
```

I expect the success: function (data) {alert("Successful");  to run as it shows AJAx request is sent .
I m not able to figure out what exactly is going wrong here

I do get failure alert ie AJAX is not sending data